# my vimeo video is not displayed right pls some advice

Tags: html, css, video, vimeo

I cannot force my video to be full width of the available space and auto height. The iframe has full width but the video has a very small size.

**CSS**

```
.embed-container {
    position: relative; 
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 100% !important; 
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: 600px !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="fourth-block">
  <div id="embed_container" class='embed-container'>
    <iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/119060390?color=de141b' id="video" frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't need a link to your website if you post the relevant code to your question. I would recommend uploading the relevant code with your attempts of fixing this issue before people start down voting your question.

Comment: I add html code now ,thx on advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
.embed-container iframe{height:100%;width:100%;}
```

OR

```
#embed_container iframe{height:100%;width:100%;}
```

This will push the iframe to 100% so you can use `.embed-container` or `embed_container` as the container for the iframe.

```
<div id="embed_container" class='embed-container'>
<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/119060390?color=de141b' id="video" frameborder='0'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: still same problem:( mybe i need delete something from .embed-container?

Comment: The above works just fine for me, create a new html document and try the above, if it works then you have some other issue with your source code.

Comment: man i did this in new html and all the same can u write me your code    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>try</title>
 <style>
 .embed-container { 
position: relative; 
height: 0; 
overflow: hidden; 
width: 100% !important; 
height: auto !important;
}

.embed-container iframe { 
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="embed_container" class='embed-container'>
<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/119060390?color=de141b' id="video" frameborder='0'></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: thx on exception.. coz of me:) ,works on new html now i will try on my site!:)

Comment: I wish you luck, when you feel your question has been answered please mark to the question so others know this has been answered.

Comment: ok man i will check and try find what is wrong with my code,still cannot figure out:(

Answer (score 0):

To start, the max-height at 600px is going to restrict it depending on browser size.

100% for some browsers may be different than others, so you are going to get varying heights.

But to fix the issue at hand, you should put the iframe in a **seperate div** and have the iframe set it for **max-height:100%** and **max-width:100%** to fit the div perfectly.

Comment: i tryed with that but still the same problem:(                .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { 
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code? Such as the video id, container id, etc. You only uploaded one chunk of CSS.

Comment: <div id="fourth-block">
     <div id="embed_container" class='embed-container'>
   ALL  HTML  <iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/119060390?color=de141b' id="video" frameborder='0'
      webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
   </div>

Comment: ALL CSS for that part .embed-container { 
position: relative; 
height: 0; 
overflow: hidden; 
width: 100% !important; 
height: auto !important;
max-height: 600px !important; 
}

.embed-container iframe { 
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: and this is only specified at id fourth-block            #fourth-block {
background:#fff;
position: relative;
}

Comment: Try adding height:auto on the .embed-container iframe. It controls the iframe differently than the div does.